# spatie/laravel-permissions assignRole method causes error [Integrity constraint violation: 1452 Cannot add or update a child row]

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.4

I'm try to assign a role to a user using a seeder but I keep getting this error:

> Integrity constraint violation: 1452 Cannot add or update a child row : a foreign key constraint fails (`internshipweb`.`user_has_roles`, CONSTRAINT `user_has_roles_role_id_foreign` FOREIGN KEY (`role_id`) REFERENCES `roles` (`id`) ...

Can't figure out why it won't work:

This is my User Model:

```
<?php

namespace App\Models\Website;

use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;
use Spatie\Permission\Traits\HasRoles;

class User extends Authenticatable
{
    use Notifiable, HasRoles;

    protected $connection = 'mysql2';

    protected $guard = 'webuser';

    protected $fillable = [
        'email', 'password', 'username', 'permissions', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'avatar'
    ];

    protected $hidden = [
        'password'
    ];


}
```

This is my seeder:

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Database\Seeder;
use App\Models\Website\User;
use Spatie\Permission\Models\Role;
use Spatie\Permission\Models\Permission;

class WebUserSeeder extends Seeder
{
    /**
     * Run the database seeds.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function run()
    {
        Role::create([
            'name' => 'admin'
        ]);

        $user = User::create([
            'email' => 'admin@gmail.com',
            'username' => 'admin',
            'password' => bcrypt('password'),
            'first_name' => 'Add',
            'last_name' => 'Min'
        ]);


        $user->assignRole('admin');
    }
}
```

I've tried clearing cache and config. I can't seem to find anyone with the same problem. If you need any more info please let me know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to add a row into your `user_has_roles` table which has a `role_id` which doesn't exist on your `roles` table. Is your `roles` table seeded yet?  You need the admin role to exist before this code runs.  If it's a later seeder, you could assign that role in your `RolesTableSeeder`

Comment: Ok I'll try that

Comment: I'm still getting the same error, and I called the `RolesTableSeeder` in the the `DatabaseSeeder` before even calling the `UsersSeeder`.

Comment: The role table also did not get populated

Comment: @chinloyal I notice the users table has its database specified but roles doesn’t, are these in the same database?

Comment: @chinloyal try my fix on my answer (I just made an edit regarding the fillable property)

Comment: @Jeff  You're absolutely right the 'Role' model was pointing to my next database, I'm gonna set the connection and see if that works

Answer (score -1):

You are getting this error because you are trying to update a row to **user_has_roles** that does not have a valid value for the **id** field 
based on the values currently stored in **roles**.

**EDIT: Ensure role_id is included as a fillable property in your user_has_roles model.**

Here is a work around/hack but be careful are this will disable all foreign key checks. If all else fails you can:

Note this is a temporary workaround that will only last the length of your current session. When you reconnect to the database this constraint will be reenabled which is a good thing.

Try run this query on your database:

```
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0
```

Comment: Foreign keys are important, he should address the problem not disable the functionality of MySQL.

Comment: @Jeff Agreed. However I had this issue recently with Laravel and after a day of being stuck on trying to fix it I turned to this fix which didn't appear to cause any issues.

Comment: I always disable foreign key checks before migrating and seeding then enable them back, so I don't think this is the fix?

Comment: @chinloyal did you see my edit? About the fillable array??